# PHP Mailer crashes website

Tags: php, phpmailer

When an email is sent from the site the whole site crashes! 
Is there any way with the code below to make it run as a cron job maybe? The problem is I'm not to familiar with cron jobs and am finding it hard to find a working solution online.

Heres the code responsible for sending mail:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'daniel_login');
define('DB_USER', 'daniel_login');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '#####');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$conn) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
     }

$recovery = $_POST['recovery'];     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$recovery'"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

   $mailto = $recovery;
   $mailSub = "" . $row['firstname'] . "'s Password Reminder";
   $mailMsg = "### CONTENT ###";
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
   $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail ->Host = "dev.#####.co.uk";
   $mail ->Port = 465; // or 587
   $mail ->IsHTML(true);
   $mail ->Username = "forgot@dev.#####.co.uk";
   $mail ->Password = "#####";
   $mail ->SetFrom("forgot@dev.#####.co.uk");
   $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
   $mail ->Body = $mailMsg;
   $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);

   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
       include 'failed.php';
   }
   else
   {
       include 'success.php';
   }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to MySQL injection. Please consider switching over to [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as this isn't suitable for production

Comment: Check your server logs and find out the reason why it's "crashing" your website. If this script it causing some mass errors, a cronjob isn't going to resolve them.

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example, and you're running an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). After that, as @IsThisJavascript says, you need to define "crashing" - we can't tell from here.

Comment: See I don't think its the script our host said that having the script put data in a mysql db and have cron jobs send them in date order. Would this work? and how would I go about doing so. We use cPanel and WHM.

Comment: Ill update the script and by crashing I mean when the script is run the whole website stops responding even the WHM doesnt load. The servers is running a reseller version of WHM and cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a year now, I hope can help other people.

I have tested on several servers with different ports. And some of those servers facing the website breakdown problem.

In my case, the server not set up for port `465` even it's said from CPanel every time we create new email. But the problem is, PHPMailer cannot reach `xx.xx.xx.xx:465` because its a close port.

In my case, I solved it by changing to port `587`. But before that, make sure your SMTP service are up and ready by try to send a mail on port `25` (default SMTP port).

Either way, you may scan all the servers ports (SMTP related port) and see which is open and available.

The website only break at the current hosting account only and not affecting other hosting account. So if you running the website under the "Reseller Hosting", the WHM will break too because your billing is in the same account. What I ve done, create another hosting to host mail service, so if the mail hosting breakdown, it will not affect the reseller / customer account.